# Codeigniter PHPExcel under linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpexcel, php-7

I have a problem. I use Codeigniter framework. I integrated the PHPExcel library. It worked fine under windows/linux and php 5.X. But now I tried it under linux (Ubuntu ) and php 7.0 . It doesn't work. Why? I enabled the php_zip, php_gd, and php_xml modules and it doesn't work either? Any Ideas?

My code id so simple

```
$this->load->library("excel");
$this->excel->load("/mba/input.xls");
echo"test";
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', "whatever");
$this->excel->save("/path/to/output.xls");
```

I can't see the test label so I think the problem is around  at the "load" part.
The path is correct, and there isn't anything in the error.log. When I checked the PHPExcel class I found the load function. I found, that the problem is that it want to load the MY_Excel class, but it isn't the part of the PHPExcel classes. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

//Controller

```
require_once APPPATH . '/third_party/Phpexcel/Bootstrap.php';



    // Create new Spreadsheet object
        $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

//Change to excel2007 excel5

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, '**Excel5**');

$writer->save('php://output');
```